# Optimal way of repartition in Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have 500 MB csv file which I am reading as a dataframe
I am looking for an optimal value of partition of this dataframe
I need to do some wide transformations and join this dataframe with another csv and so I have below 3 approaches now for re-partitioning this dataframe

1. df.repartition(no. of cores)
2. Re-partitioning the dataframe as per calculation 500MB/128MB~ 4 partitions so as to have at least 128MB data in each partition
3. Re-partitioning dataframe using specific columns of csv so as to co-locate data in same partitions

I want to know which of these option will be best for having parallel computation and processing in Spark 2.4

Answer (score 0):

If you know the data very well then using the columns to partition the data works best. However, repartitioning based on either based on the block size and the no of cores are subject to change whenever the cluster configuration changes and for every environment you need to make those changes if your cluster configuration is different in higher environments. So, all in all going to with Data driven repartitioning is the better approach.